# Keep red and blue boxes fixed in corners of container during horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

Using only CSS, can I keep the red and blue boxes in their respective corners while scrolling horizontally?

This container will be in the center of my page with additional content on either side, so I don't think `position: fixed` is a viable option as it takes the boxes out of the flow of the page.

Is there a way to keep these boxes in the top left and right corners of my container while I scroll?

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kk45v2xd/1/)

Comment: Not without restucturing. The closest you will be is `position:absolute` but I'm guessing this isn't what you are after either. *Maybe* `position:sticky`?

Comment: @Paulie_D what would you recommend in terms of restucturing?

Comment: You need some sort of frame that holds everything in place then scrolls an extra inner container I'd guess. Probably a bit messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take your buttons and wrap them in a container that is the same shape.  Make that div relative and then position them absolutely within the new container div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute-container">
    <div class="stay_left"></div>
    <div class="stay_right"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

the CSS for the new container:

```
.absolute-container{
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and the added lines to your buttons:

```
.stay_left{
  //float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.stay_right{
  //float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

You can also remove the floats because they are no longer necessary.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfriedl2/h7s066ho/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a structure like this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
     <div class="stay_left"></div>
     <div class="stay_right"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muysmmmw/2/)**

Like Paulie_D said, it requires some messy restructuring.  Basically need an outer div to span the width of the page with position: absolute to take it out of the page flow and lay it on top of the container.  Then an inner div with the same width as the container and margin:auto so it's centered.  Then you can float the boxes to the left and right.